# Getting blur amchart image

Tags: charts, amcharts, amcharts4

Using amcharts4 legacy version
const chartImageData = this.chart?.exporting.getImage("png")

I'm getting blur chart image via getImage("png").

I'm able to get clear image when calling getImage while chart initialisation
But when I move scrollbars, etc. And then hit getImage then getting blurred image
same code same everything for both.

Any help will be appreciated